# How to list the top 3 nearest values to a reference number in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, xlookup

I am new to excel and would like to ask: What's the formula to display the top 3 numbers that are nearest to the reference value of 30?

Example I have a list of numbers:
10, 11, 12, 27, 28, 29, 43, 44, 45

And the reference value is: 30.

My current formula using Xlookup only displays: 29 but not 27, 28.

Ideally I would want it to display something like this:

Reference value: 30

Top 3 values that are nearest to Reference values

1. 29
2. 28
3. 27

This referencing will eventually be conducted in data values stored in a different excel file (i.e. the list of numbers will be stored in a separate excel file).

Thank you so much in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=INDEX(SORTBY(A1:A9,ABS(A1:A9-B1),,A1:A9,-1),{1,2,3})
```

This would first sort the numbers on the ascending difference between the number and your reference value. If there are theoretical ties between say 29 and 31 it will then further sort on highest to lowest.

[image]

Comment: Right, the example just showed smaller values, so I interpreted it as "less than". Thank you.